# Google Assistant SDK

Tags: python

This is for a graduation project. I had troubles with installing Google Assistant SDK, thanks to a lot of helpful people I made my next step. But my next step is sadly my next dead end.

This is the next step:

```
python3 -m googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers –client-secrets path\to\your\client_secret_XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
```

There is a return:

> No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers

So I Googled that and tried the steps that are suggested:

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless
```

The first one worked well, the second one sadly not. I read in another forum that if its in terminal I should do it without `--headless`.

```
(myenvname) Firass-MacBook-Pro:myenvname firashachem$ python3 -m googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers 
-–client-secrets 
Users/firashachem/Desktop/client_secret_*****ntent.com.json 
/Users/firashachem/myproject/myenvname/bin/python3: No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /Users/firashachem/Desktop/googleassistant/client_secret_*****.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
Usage: google-oauthlib-tool [OPTIONS]
Error: Missing option "--scope".
(myenvname) Firass-MacBook-Pro:myenvname firashachem$ google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /Users/firashachem/Desktop/googleassistant/client_secret_****.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
Usage: google-oauthlib-tool [OPTIONS]
(myenvname) Firass-MacBook-Pro:myenvname firashachem$ google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /Users/firashachem/Desktop/googleassistant/client_secret_****.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
Usage: google-oauthlib-tool [OPTIONS]

Error: Missing option "--scope".
(myenvname) Firass-MacBook-Pro:myenvname firashachem$  --scope 
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save
```

Comment: Would you replace that image with the text? That would be much easier for folks to read.

Comment: Thank your for editing and improving my question, its all new to me and I have no ideas about 'dos and donts' I will replace the image. thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are missing your service file.

Comment: how can I fix that? sorry I am really bad at this and it is all new to me.

Comment: To add code formatting, select the text and click the `{}` code button in the toolbar. It adds a four-space indent to all lines, which is the Markdown way of formatting code/logs. There's no need to use backticks for block formatting, so remove those.

Comment: so fixed the grey box issue, thanks guys I appreciate! now back to the context of my problem, I really have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @FH92 what are you actually trying to do.  You seem to be following a tutorial or something copy-paste.  Can you link it?

Comment: My goal is to work with google home and teach it stuff but not wit api because it is too simple my prof wants me to code stuff like "blink lights" I bought the Philips hue. I am following so many tutorials but the both main tutorials: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine/    and  https://9to5google.com/2017/05/09/how-to-install-google-assistant-mac-pc-computer/

Comment: Please just realize right now that the above _is_ a google api.  I doubt you'd be able to talk to the google home device any other way, except if you hijack its drivers.  If you are at peace with talking to APIs, then please make sure that all of the required packages are installed.  `No module named...` suggests that they are not

Comment: Ah ok, but what is the google assistant sdk about? I found lots of json commands. When you go to api you -> integrations -> new project you can decide if you go with api.ai or actions sdk. and I need the actions sdk. thats why I am doing all these installations.

Comment: Ok.  Go to the google docs and set up your environment properly.  Quick google search gave me something like this:  https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/.  
I'm fairly sure that your google environment is just not properly set up.  I've never worked with google for home, so I'm not going to go and copy paste a google tutorial here.
However, it looks like you are having troubles with your authentication. Do you need a service account key?  It looks like that json file you are referencing.  If that is a service account key, is it valid?

Comment: Also, take a look at https://www.novaspirit.com/2017/05/23/voice-activated-google-assistant-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Also, have you tried running that command of yours with the `--scope` option?  Doesn't look like you have.  Does something need to go after `--scope`?  
I realize this is a big learning curve.  But go to a tutorial, take a deep breath, and start at the beginning.  Read every line of explanation.  
For more speed, use less haste

Comment: @Roman thanks a lot for all your help! I will go through your links you have sent me. hm, the tutorial I did this like 50 time without exaggeration. To the `--scope` option I have no idea what that is, I only know that it was in the code I used. hm, in my 3 years of studying I was only focussed on the courses but never coded by myself. I need to learn like everything.  Thanks a lot again, I really appreciate. I will let you know about my progress.

Comment: There is one thing I still don't get. Do I need a Raspberry Pi 3 or not. To create projects for google home and Philips hue I only need those two devices and terminal right?

Comment: hey @Roman I made progress with my project but now I am stuck again. Can you help me out please? check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912724/install-portaudio19-dev-libffi-dev-libssl-dev

Comment: @FH92 yes, it looks like you need the rasberry pi.  Or another linux machine.  This doesn't seem to be made easy for mac.  Once you are using a rasberry pi, you can use the `apt-get` package manager instead of `brew`.  That should fix the problem in your link, as per comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command.

```
(myenvname) Firass-MacBook-Pro:myenvname firashachem$ google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /Users/firashachem/Desktop/googleassistant/client_secret_****.apps.googleusercontent.com.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless
```

Terminal asked for a authorization code ("Enter the authorization code: ").

You can see a link above this line(ex:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1****=offline).
 open this link in browser and log in to the google account and authenicate.
now you can see  a authorization code in your browser copy this code and paste it on terminal and press enter.
Now everything will work fine and you will get the file "credentials.json".

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked fine :) but still need to fix the problem I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912724/install-portaudio19-dev-libffi-dev-libssl-dev   I am trying to fix it without raspberry pi, somehow it works without. and there is a problem when I type the push to talk code, my terminal keeps going with: "Press enter to send a new request" then it records audio for 10 sec and this repeats all the time

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: you can see upper arrow and down arrow in the left side of answer,press upper arrow button to vote for my answer.