# Install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev

Tags: json, sdk

This work is for a graduation project. I had troubles with installing Google Assistant SDK, but I fixed that now. But I am stuck. I need to install

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

but I think I need

```
brew install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

But then I receive this:

```
brew install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
Error: No available formula with the name "portaudio19-dev" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula..
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions. (I have downvoted as I've edited this out of your questions before).

Comment: If you are stuck doing this in a Mac, install VirtualBox and Vagrant, and just use Linux proper. That may be a lot faster than messing around with Homebrew.

Comment: @halfer  I am not using it to receive faster answers. it is because I have limited time to make this work otherwise my professor will shut my project down and I need to delay my graduation and I will lose lots of money and a really good job offer. Sorry but in my opinion it is urgent, but if it does not count, I won't repeat it.